Does this poetic translation sound good for English speakers?
I am trying to translate Pushkin. This is an excerpt from his "Tale about a dead princess and seven knights", which is itself a variation of the Grimm brothers' fairy tale "Snowwhite".
As a dowry she received
Just one mirror, it's believed;
But this mirror was unique,
For it had the gift to speak.
With this mirror she would be
Kind and cheerful, wild and free,
With it playfully she'd chatter
And would ask, no idle matter:
"Mirror mine, oh please do say,
Tell the truth to me today;
As you did the day before,
Tell me, tell me, I implore:
Am I fairest in creation,
Most rose-cheeked in every nation?"
And the mirror would reply:
"You're the fairest, none deny;
You're the fairest, as you know,
Every day, it's always so.
Then the Queen would laugh with glee,
Shrug her shoulders merrily,
Wink her eyes in pure delight,
Snap her fingers swift and bright,
Twirl around with hands on hips,
Joy upon her royal lips.

Original:
Ей в приданое дано
Было зеркальце одно;
Свойство зеркальце имело:
Говорить оно умело.
С ним одним она была
Добродушна, весела,
С ним приветливо шутила
И, красуясь, говорила:
«Свет мой, зеркальце! Скажи,
Да всю правду доложи:
Я ль на свете всех милее,
Всех румяней и белее?»
И ей зеркальце в ответ:
«Ты, конечно, спору нет;
Ты, царица, всех милее,
Всех румяней и белее».
И царица хохотать,
И плечами пожимать,
И подмигивать глазами,
И прищёлкивать перстами,
И вертеться подбочась,
Гордо в зеркальце глядясь.

https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/Сказка_о_мёртвой_царевне_и_о_семи_богатырях_(Пушкин)

Sorry, but requests for proofreading are off-topic.

I don't know Russian but your translation is clever.   The only phrase that gave me pause was "Wink her eyes"
